# Scrollviewer is scrolling down on its own

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, devexpress, scrollviewer

I've got a problem with a `ListBox` (plain WPF, `System.Windows.Controls.ListBox`) with items that contain a `ListBox` (also plain WPF) themselves. In my production app (which uses the DevExpress-controls), when the outer `ListBox` is created, it scrolls down immediately (yet visibly) down so that the first item in the last inner `ListBox` is visible.

I've tried to reproduce this behavior with a minimal app without DevExpress and one that uses DevExpress. Neither shows that behavior.

I've attached a handler to `ScrollChanged` of the `ScrollViewer` of the (outer) `ListBox`, and I see the event that causes the scroll, but I cannot figure out where it's originating from.

Sidenote: if I make one of the `ListBox`es (doesn't matter whether inner or outer)  a DevExpress-`ListBoxEdit`, the scrolling-problem goes away. I cannot do this however, as I get `InvalidOperationException`s about collections changing during enumeration when I click on items. And I don't need or want the `ListBoxEdit` functionality anyway.

Second sidenote: I've tried removing the theme for the outer `ListBox` (`ThemeManager.ThemeName="None"`), but to no effect.

So the question is *how can I find out who causes the scrolling* (to prevent him from doing so)?

Update: focussing the first item of the outer listbox does not change anything.

Update: subscribing `RequestBringIntoView` and setting `Handled=true` solves the problem, but only as long as I break in there. Without the breakpoint, it does nothing. The stacktrace itself doesn't tell me anything:

```
bei MyApp.MyAppControls.BackToToTopListBox.OnRequestBringIntoView(Object sender, RequestBringIntoViewEventArgs requestBringIntoViewEventArgs)
bei System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
bei System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
bei System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
bei System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
bei System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer.ExecuteNextCommand()
bei System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer.OnLayoutUpdated(Object sender, EventArgs e)
bei System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.fireLayoutUpdateEvent()
bei System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
bei System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayoutCallback(Object arg)
bei System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
bei System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
bei System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
bei System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
bei System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
bei System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
bei MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(Object obj)
bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
bei MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
bei System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
bei System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
bei System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
bei MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
bei MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
bei System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
bei System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
bei System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
bei MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
bei MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
bei MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
bei System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
bei System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
bei System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
bei MyApp.MAT.App.Main()
```

Comment: You might want to emphasise you're talking about standard WPF ListBoxes, which isn't clear on the first read. With DevExpress focused items can be brought into view, perhaps that what's happening with the last ListBox? To remove the theme, you can have a look at [this post](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T642497/standard-wpf-controls-affected-by-devexpress-themes).

Comment: None of the items is selected and none _should_ be focussed, but I'll investigate into that. Regarding the theme, I've tried removing the theme from the whole app or from the outer listbox or from the inner ones only, but that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: To scratch DevExpress from the list, you could take it one further and override any (theme independent) implicit styles by setting an explicit style (that's not BasedOn) on each of the ListBoxes.

Comment: Questions: 1. What happens if you set ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll to false and if that does not stop your behavior 2. what happens if you disable IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem

Comment: @Nebelkraehe `CanContentScroll=true` solves the problem, but I lose smooth scrolling. `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem=False` doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @Funk setting an empty style explicitly on both listboxes dosn't change a thing.

Comment: Allright. What if you subscribe to the "RequestBringIntoView" -Event and set the event to Handled=true inside the Handler? (you could also use the Handler to take a look inside the CallStack to get an idea what causes the scrolling)

Comment: May you provide the xaml ?

Comment: The xaml is hundreds and hundreds of lines in total, I don't think that makes sense. I really don't need someone to do the debugging for me, I need a hint on how to debug this at all.

Comment: Are you referencing any of your ListBoxes from code behind? If yes, remove that code to see if the 'ghost-scrolling' is gone. As you've already tried to reproduce the bug without success, I'd step by step, remove all sorts of stuff from the application. After every step, verify if the error is still there. Doing so, breaks the app - which is ok as long as you can still navigate to your listboxes. This way you can narrow down where the bug is comming from. I'd start by removing XAML resources within your view and then global ResourceDictionaries. Consider this approach as a last resort only.

Comment: Are you setting the selected/active list box (inner) when it is created? IIRC a scroll viewer will automatically scroll to a selected/active object in a collection, so if you're creating a new list box object and adding it to the collection contained within the outer list box/scroll viewer, it may be being set as the selected item by default and therefore the scroll viewer navigates to it automatically.

Comment: @ataraxia both inner and outer listboxes indeed have their `SelectedValue` bound. In fact, all the inner listboxes to the same property on the outer listbox's view model. But at startup, and when the scrolling happens, the value is `null`. Also, the minimal app that uses the same setup does not show the scrolling.

Comment: could you maybe replace the inner listbox with an itemscontrol? I guess you don't want scrolling elements inside the outer scrolling element

Comment: ah, I just see that you bind both of the selectedvalues and the itemscontrol doesn't do that... although you could maybe do it with radio buttons re-themed to look like list items inside the itemscontrol - you'd still have the selection working that way

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the ScrollViewer from a ListBox by changing its control template to something much simpler:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ItemsPresenter />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ListBox.Template>
    ...
</ListBox>
```

However, I question the value of nesting ListBoxes. Remember that each ListBox is a Selector and has a concept of which item is "selected". Does it really make sense to have a selected item inside a selected item, inside a selected item?

I would suggest changing the "inner" ListBoxes to simple ItemsControls so that the nested lists can't have selected items. That would make for a much simpler user experience. You may still need to retemplate the inner ItemsControls in the same way to remove the scrollbars, but at least the user won't get confused about which item is "selected".

Comment: I can't remove the scrollviewer, I want it to scroll, just not immediately when it's created.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the auto scroll by blocking ListBoxItem's RequestBringIntoView event.

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <EventSetter Event="RequestBringIntoView" Handler="ListBoxItem_RequestBringIntoView"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

void ListBoxItem_RequestBringIntoView(object sender, RequestBringIntoViewEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```